# cannot find symbol variable k

Tags: java

When I compile this and run it I get "cannot find symbol variable k" But when I define the symbol variable it says it has already been defined. Why is this?
{

```
private int numBars;    // number of bars to be displayed
int barHeight[];        // array of bar heights
int swapDelay;          // The delay between the original display and the second display.
int bar1, bar2;         // Indexes of 2 bars to be swapped.

public void init()
{
    numBars   = enterIntGUI("How many bars will be displayed?  {1-1000}");
    bar1      = enterIntGUI("What is the index of the 1st bar to be swapped?  {0-"+(numBars-1)+"}");
    bar2      = enterIntGUI("What is the index of the 2nd bar to be swapped?  {0-"+(numBars-1)+"}");
    swapDelay = 3000;
    barHeight = new int[numBars];
    getBarValues();     
}

public void getBarValues()
{     
  int list[] = new int[20];
    list[k] = Expo.random(10,640);
    for (int k = 1; k < 20; k++)
    System.out.println("list[" + k + "] = " + list[k]);


}
```

Answer (score 3):

`k` is used before it is defined. Perhaps you want

```
for (int k = 1; k < 20; k++) {
    list[k] = Expo.random(10,640);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to access `k` before it is defined or has a value.

You need to modify it this way:

```
public void getBarValues()
{     
    int list[] = new int[20];
    for (int k = 1; k < 20; k++) {
       list[k] = Expo.random(10,640);
       System.out.println("list[" + k + "] = " + list[k]);
    }
}
```

Comment: before it is even defined, rather.

Comment: ...and this is why I hate `if`, `while` or `for` statements that leave out the curly braces because "it's just one statement".